# Oracle SOA composite aborts after successfully selecting from MYSQL table

Tags: mysql, oracle, weblogic, soa

Using SOA Suite 11.1.1.6, I have a requirement that requires selecting records from a table in MySQL. I have the datasource created with Support Global Transactions checked and the option Logging Last Resource selected. On the connection Factory I have the jndi name entered in the xaDataSourceName and the platformClassName is  `org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.Oracle10Platform`. When I run the composite, it successfully selects the records from the table but aborts when the composite completes with the following:

error while attempting to process the message `com.collaxa.cube.engine.dispatch.message.invoke.InvokeInstanceMessage`. The reported exception is:

> Error committing transaction:;
>   nested exception is: javax.transaction.xa.XAException:
>   JDBC driver does not support XA, hence cannot be a participant in two-phase commit. To force this participation, set the GlobalTransactionsProtocol attribute to LoggingLastResource (recommended) or EmulateTwoPhaseCommit for the Data Source = MySqlDS

Any ideas?

Comment: Recreate your datasource and don't set it as an XA with two phase commit. For Oracle i have to set it as Oracle Drive thin for instance connection. For mysql you'll find something that don't include two phase commit

Comment: Hi, that's what I have it set to, a non XA Datasource. On the transaction tab I have "Logging Last Resource".

Comment: This has been resolved, there was an issue with the Weblogic Server itself that the sys admin had to resolved when fixing a crashed issue.

Comment: What was the error ? Wrong configuration of the Datasource ? Could you write down what he did as an answer so future people googling the issue know what you did to fix it ? :)

Comment: My apologies, I have been unable to get a response from my clients IT group on how this was fixed.